# retrieve data from firebase to recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I tried to retrieve data from firebase to recyclerview when the application is run, nothing appears, in logcat shows error:

*com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Double to String*

This my firebase:
[My firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9dPZ.png)

and this my adapter.java:

```
  package com.example.aplikasita;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    ArrayList<User> list;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        User user= list.get(position);
        holder.current.setText(user.getCurrent());
        holder.bus_voltagevoltage.setText(user.getBus_voltagevoltage());
        holder.power.setText(user.getPower());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView current, bus_voltagevoltage, power;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        current=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvarus);
        bus_voltagevoltage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvtegangan);
        power=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdaya);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: share us database code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

```
    User user= list.get(position);
    holder.current.setText(user.getCurrent());
    holder.bus_voltagevoltage.setText(user.getBus_voltagevoltage());
    holder.power.setText(user.getPower());
```

}

Use this:

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

```
    User user= list.get(position);
    holder.current.setText(user.getCurrent().toString());
    holder.bus_voltagevoltage.setText(user.getBus_voltagevoltage().toString());
    holder.power.setText(user.getPower().toString());
```

}